# Accessing Data from Multidimensional Arrays -Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, multidimensional-array, response

I need help accessing data from ajax response json array.

Back end PHP script returns an array like:

```
[
    [
        {
            AccessID: "178638920205",
            ActionDate: "2018-12-18 01:36:56",
            ActionDescription: "Richard Mahdi logged out at 2018-12-18 01:36:56 AM.",
            ActionType: "Log Out",
            Record_Number: "6890701492",
            ResponseLevel: "0",
            custNames: "Richard Mahdi",
            id: "9",
            thumbNameClass: "qRichardS",
            useThumbNail: "https://subdomain.domain.com/adminodocs2019001/richard686827.png"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            AccessID: "178638920205",
            ActionDate: "2018-12-18 01:35:32",
            ActionDescription: "Richard Mahdi sent Feed Back. Feedback Type: Request. If Feedback is a complaint, you might want to address that immediately via direct communication. View Feedback message from Feedback Section",
            ActionType: "Feed Back",
            Record_Number: "6890701492",
            ResponseLevel: "5",
            custNames: "Richard Mahdi",
            id: "8",
            thumbNameClass: "gRichardB",
            useThumbNail: "https://subdomain.domain.com/adminodocs2019001/richard686827.png"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            AccessID: "178638920205",
            ActionDate: "2018-12-18 01:33:25",
            ActionDescription: "Richard Mahdi sent Feed Back. Feedback Type: Complaints. If Feedback is a complaint, you might want to address that immediately via direct communication. View Feedback message from Feedback Section",
            ActionType: "Feed Back",
            Record_Number: "6890701492",
            ResponseLevel: "5",
            custNames: "Richard Mahdi",
            id: "7",
            thumbNameClass: "fRichardU",
            useThumbNail: "https://subdomain.domain.com/adminodocs2019001/richard686827.png"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            AccessID: "178638920205",
            ActionDate: "2018-12-18 01:32:27",
            ActionDescription: "Richard Mahdi successfully completed Initial Account Setup. No action required.",
            ActionType: "Initial Account Setup",
            Record_Number: "6890701492",
            ResponseLevel: "0",
            custNames: "Richard Mahdi",
            id: "6",
            thumbNameClass: "tRichardD",
            useThumbNail: "https://subdomain.domain.com/adminodocs2019001/richard686827.png"
        }
    ]
]
```

Tried several ways of processing the data and accessing the array elements. Currently stuck with:

```js
var datatosend = { 'adminoID': "12345"};
 
$.ajax({
    url: "dtrack.php",
    data: datatosend,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        $.each(response,function(x,y){
            console.log(y.ActionDescription);
            alert(y.ActionDescription);
        });  
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Grateful for all suggestions or solutions.

Comment: what? Please condense the raw data into an applicable bit, then tell us what you're trying to achieve. aka, how are you currently trying to access the data, what you expected and what happened instead.

Comment: Apparently this should work, since you are iterating the array and accessing the ActionDescription property that according to the example that samples exist in the array. You could try is to print the array from the navigated console and verify that it is arriving as a javascript object...Also you should also check if there is any cross-request blocking by the server

Comment: You lost me at "how are you trying to access the data". I would think that's obvious enough. The response data is as shown (and thanks to @meW for proper editing). Its an ajax response and I want to access each element of the array. Currently tried: $.each(response,function(x,y){
        console.log(y.ActionDescription);
        alert(y.ActionDescription);}). Clearly not working.

Comment: @MatiasAguirreLuco Thanks. Will verify that the response is json object.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet Thanks for your inputs and edits. Horrified I can't replicate your suggestion, which should work pretty straightforward. Taking a 100th look at my PHP script that returns the array.

Comment: Note that the data as shown above is a JS object, not a JSON string.  If your output looks like `{..., foo: 42, ...}` then it's not JSON.  It needs an additional set of quotes: `{..., "foo": 42, ...}`.  But I imagine PHP has a JSON stringification function/library you could use for this.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes. That goes without saying. Response was returned using "echo json_encode($responseSend)". But I think where it is in the php script might have a bearing on why the returned array data is weirdly formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this in your `success` handler:

```
response.forEach(x => x.forEach(y => {
  console.log(y.ActionDescription)
}))
```

You could clearly do something similar with `jQuery#each`, but there is little reason to use that on the modern web.  `Array.prototype.forEach` is fine.

The language has no real multi-dimensional arrays.  Arrays of arrays is as close as it comes.  But if the inner arrays always have a single element each, I would urge you to flatten them, as they're pretty well useless.

```js
const response = [        
    [{"id":"9","ActionDate":"2018-12-18 01:36:56","custNames":"Richard Mahdi","Record_Number":"6890701492","AccessID":"178638920205","ActionType":"Log Out","ActionDescription":"Richard Mahdi logged out at 2018-12-18 01:36:56 AM.","ResponseLevel":"0","thumbNameClass":"qRichardS","useThumbNail":"https:\/\/subdomain.domain.com\/adminodocs2019001\/richard686827.png"}],
    [{"id":"8","ActionDate":"2018-12-18 01:35:32","custNames":"Richard Mahdi","Record_Number":"6890701492","AccessID":"178638920205","ActionType":"Feed Back","ActionDescription":"Richard Mahdi sent Feed Back. Feedback Type: Request. If Feedback is a complaint, you might want to address that immediately via direct communication. View Feedback message from Feedback Section","ResponseLevel":"5","thumbNameClass":"gRichardB","useThumbNail":"https:\/\/subdomain.domain.com\/adminodocs2019001\/richard686827.png"}],
    [{"id":"7","ActionDate":"2018-12-18 01:33:25","custNames":"Richard Mahdi","Record_Number":"6890701492","AccessID":"178638920205","ActionType":"Feed Back","ActionDescription":"Richard Mahdi sent Feed Back. Feedback Type: Complaints. If Feedback is a complaint, you might want to address that immediately via direct communication. View Feedback message from Feedback Section","ResponseLevel":"5","thumbNameClass":"fRichardU","useThumbNail":"https:\/\/subdomain.domain.com\/adminodocs2019001\/richard686827.png"}],
    [{"id":"6","ActionDate":"2018-12-18 01:32:27","custNames":"Richard Mahdi","Record_Number":"6890701492","AccessID":"178638920205","ActionType":"Initial Account Setup","ActionDescription":"Richard Mahdi successfully completed Initial Account Setup. No action required.","ResponseLevel":"0","thumbNameClass":"tRichardD","useThumbNail":"https:\/\/subdomain.domain.com\/adminodocs2019001\/richard686827.png"}]
]

response.forEach(x => x.forEach(y => {
  console.log(y.ActionDescription)
}))
```

Comment: Yes! You did it! Thanks. Your statement "You could clearly do something similar with jQuery#each, but there is little reason to use that on the modern web.  Array.prototype.forEach is fine," made me to realise i needed to focus on the source producing the array.